# Xamarin iOS add dynamic amount of Views to StackView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add a dynamic amount of xib Views to a Stackpanel which is inside a UIView which is inside a UIScrollView.

[image]

Actually I am doing this completely with code...

```
// These 3 values are completely variable
private int viewHeight = 100;
private int stackviewSpacing = 8;
private int countViews = 7;

for (int i = 0; i < countViews; i++)
{
    SessionViewItem sView = SessionViewItem.Create();
    sView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, i * viewHeight + i * stackviewSpacing, this.svSessions.Frame.Width, viewHeight);
    svSessions.AddSubview(sView);
}
```

... but I think this could not be the best solution.

**Question 1:** Is there a better solution to add the Views to the Stackpanel?

Also I only can see the first 5 items because the UIScrollView does not resize to it's content size.

**Question 2:** What do I need to make the UIScrollView scrollable for the whole content?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why don't you use a `UITableView` instead?

Comment: Why should I use *UITableView*? Are there any benefits over *UIStackView*?

Comment: because a "dynamic" amounts of views in a "ScrollView" sounds to me like you're trying to replicate what `UITableVIew` has been designed for.

Comment: Yes, UItableview is better option.  you can read on how to use it from here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xamarin.ios/5907/create-and-use-custom-prototype-table-cells-in-xamarin-ios-using-storyboard#t=201702011308121045394

Comment: Alright, I will try it with a `UITableView` but because all UIs are made with a `UIScrollView` it would be nice to see how it would be done